# What is a Jersey Filter?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, servlet-filters

I want to know basically what a Jersey filter is and how is it related to a servlet filter? Are they the same? What are the main patterns of using a Jersey Filter?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first part of your question may be answered in the [Jersey documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html). A Jersey filter is not the same as a servlet filter.
There are two filters included in Jersey, a filter for logging requests and one for compression (GZip).
Another use case for a custom filter would be authentication or authorization.

Comment: Here's a better link: https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#filters-and-interceptors

Comment: Latest link appears to be https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html

Answer (score 22):

Technically, a Jersey filter is not a servlet filter. However, you can use a Jersey filter for many of the same things that you would use a servlet filter for - cross-cutting concerns that affect all (or some, or most) the services that Jersey exposes.

As the previous answer states, Jersey comes with two filters, but you can usefully implement the Jersey interfaces [`ContainerRequestFilter`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) or/and [`ContainerResponseFilter`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html) if you don't want to extend them. You're not limited to these two.

Another Jersey interface to keep in mind is [`ResourceFilter`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ResourceFilter.html)  - this interface can be implemented for a filter that affects only some of the services.